# How do I replace UIAlertController so that I don't need to press a Continue button

Tags: ios, swift

Question rephrased:

I have some buttons on the screen that display answers to a random question (multiple choice).  Looks basically like:

```
ViewDidLoad() {
    some cosmetic stuff blah blah blah
    nextQuestion()
}

func nextQuestion() {
    display question
    set button text (answers)
}

@IBAction func getAnswer(_sender: UIButton) {
    check answer
    do the UIAlertController thing
}
```

When a button is pressed UIAlertController displays the result, then, after pressing Continue, the next question and set of answers are displayed.  (Is ViewDidLoad called whenever a UIAlertController is discharged?)

This works except that I don't want to have to press two buttons to get to the next question (the selected answer and the Continue button).  Once one of the buttons is pressed, I want the next next question and set of answers displayed immediately.

Using Xcode 9.0 and Swift 4.  (And yes, I am new to Swift.)

Comment: Why the downgrade?  I have spent hours searching for an answer, tried multiple things from moving the call to ViewWillAppear to SetNeedsDisplay, etc.  Seems this should be so trivial, but something is eluding me...

Comment: What part in particular is eluding you when you break the problem into pieces? You know how to display a UILabel onscreen? Set its text dynamically?

Comment: You're probably getting down voted because you're not asking a technical question. UIAlertController has a very specific task, and Apple even wants to limit how you use it according to their Human Interface Guidelines. It sounds like you're looking to make a custom modal popup, something like this: https://medium.com/lifesum-healthy-living-simplified/presenting-a-uiviewcontroller-modally-with-a-transparent-background-the-cool-way-b79eb0abd423

Comment: I have no problem with setting the label's text dynamically.  How do I have the nextQuestion function called again after the answer is displayed?  UIController seems to refresh the display (reload the view?)  I can do this by adding another button, but I just want the result displayed and the function called again.  I do NOT want a popup.

Comment: Another hour wasted fruitlessly searching for answers.  
I thought this was a forum to get help when you couldn't figure things out yourself.  Thank you so much, you two who downgraded me, who probably could have easily answered in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want the app and user interaction to look, one approach would be:

- create two "container" views: `viewQ` and `viewA`
- `viewQ` will have the Question and a set of answers
- `viewA` will have the feedback for the Question, along with your Continue button
- when an answer is selected, instead of showing a `UIAlertController`, set the text of your Feedback label(s) in `viewA`, *hide* `viewQ` and *show* `viewA`
- when Continue is selected, do the reverse... populate the Question and Answer elements of `viewQ`, *hide* `viewA` and *show* `viewQ`

---

Or, if you don't want a "Continue" button at all...

- create just One view
- "top" portion of view has a label for the "Question" and a set of buttons for the "Answers"
- "bottom" portion of the view has a label for the "Feedback"

When an Answer is selected, set the text of the Feedback label as desired, and set the Question label text and Answer button titles for the next question.

Much simpler :)

Comment: Thank you, DonMag.  The problem is that I don't want a Continue button - that's the rub.  
I just want to show a message in the label and have the next question and set of answers loaded so that the user may answer without having to ask to see the next question.

Comment: Your edited reply is exactly what I want!  Now, how do I get it to load the the next question and set of answers?

Comment: Where is your Q & A data coming from? Do you have it in a local data file / database? Is it pulling it from a remote service? Have you gotten to the point where you are at least loading and displaying the first question and answers?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. The only problem I am having is getting the next set loaded as soon as the button is pressed.

Comment: @Greg - I can't tell you how to do that, without knowing how you have your data set up to begin with. You need to just start writing the code... first, build a dataset - it could be an array, a dictionary, a database, a web service, whatever. Once you have your data, fill in the fields and buttons for the first question. Then handle a button tap on an answer, and fill in the feedback label and then get the next record from you data and fill in the question label and answer buttons, and so on.

Comment: My test version uses an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entire thing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var displayQuestion: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rightOrWrongLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myScore: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var answer1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var answer2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var answer3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var answer4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var answer5: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    questions += ["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7", "q8", "q9", "q10"]
    answers += ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10"]
    qIndexArray += [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7,8 ,9]

    nextQuestion()
}


func nextQuestion(action: UIAlertAction! = nil) {
    // shuffle index array
    qIndexArray = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: qIndexArray) as! [Int]

    answer1.setTitle(answers[qIndexArray[0]], for: .normal)
    answer2.setTitle(answers[qIndexArray[1]], for: .normal)
    answer3.setTitle(answers[qIndexArray[2]], for: .normal)
    answer4.setTitle(answers[qIndexArray[3]], for: .normal)
    answer5.setTitle(answers[qIndexArray[4]], for: .normal)

    // generate a random Int from 0 and 4
    correctAnswer = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 5)

    displayQuestion.text = questions[Int(qIndexArray[correctAnswer])]
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var title: String
    if sender.tag == Int(correctAnswer) {
        title = "Correct!"
        score += 1
    } else {
        title = "Wrong"
    }
    rightOrWrongLabel.text = title
    myScore.text = "Current score is \(score)."

     // Generate a UIAlert to display score
     let alertControl = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "Current score is \(score).", preferredStyle: .alert)
     alertControl.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: nextQuestion))
     present(alertControl, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

When I click on one of the buttons it will pop up the Alert, wait for me to continue, then load a new set.

As you can see, I already have the right/wrong message and the score.  I want to get rid of the UIAlertController so that a new set is displayed immediately without having to push the Continue button.  Play this 20 times and press 10 buttons rather than 20.

Comment: So, just remove the 3 "alertControl" lines and replace them with `nextQuestion()`.

Comment: That works!  I knew it should be something trivial.  I wonder how I missed that - I would swear I had tried that - more than once since it makes the most sense - but I guess not.
Thank you VERY much DonMag!

Comment: I should add that I emptied the Derived Data folder right before doing this, so that may have been the culprit.